# Automorphisms of $Z_{p^{i_1}}*Z_{p^{i_2}}*...*Z_{p^{i_n}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $Z_{p^{i_1}}\times Z_{p^{i_2}}\times\cdots\times Z_{p^{i_n}}=\langle a_1,...,a_n\rangle$, then each automorphism of this group is the forms as follows,

$$\sigma:a_j\rightarrow a_1^{\ell_{j1}}\cdots a_n^{\ell_{jn}}.$$

Then how to give the necessary and sufficient condition of every $\ell_{jk}$? 
Or can you give me some references about this question? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to be clear: do you consider the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) $\times$ or the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) $*$?

Comment: I consider the direct product $\times$, thank you.

Comment: This looks promising: Automorphisms of finite abelian groups http://www.msri.org/people/members/chillar/files/autabeliangrps.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! I have downloaded it, it is very useful. Also I searched another paper about this problem: AUTOMORPHISMS OF FINITE ABELIAN GROUPS, written by J.N.S. Bidwell and M.J. Curran,Department of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Otago, Dunedin, New Zealand. But I cannot downloaded it. Can you help me? Thank you! http://ria.metapress.com/content/b656w36751060h77/. My email is: jbliu010@gmail.com.